# Can't install Wi-Fi driver on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: drivers, server, wireless, 22.04

I've got a small problem on my Ubuntu Server 22.04 that I made a few days ago. I'm a noob at this and I'm just trying to set it up to host some game servers and personal project of mine. During this endeavor, I was connected to internet via Ethernet so everything was fine, but now I don't have access to any anymore. That's why I decided to buy one on Amazon, an Asus PCE-AC51.

I got the drivers [here](https://www.asus.com/fr/networking-iot-servers/adapters/all-series/pce-ac51/helpdesk_download/?model2Name=PCE-AC51) (I took the last one, for EU), moved it on a USB stick and mounted it on my server. I thought it would be as easy as just running the install.sh script and everything would be alright.

[image: screenshot]

I keep getting this error and I don't know how to fix it. I saw people redownloading the `rfl8723de` but I don't know how to do that without prior connection to internet.

I can't access internet via this machine, but I can put stuff on my USB stick and install stuff that way.

I already reinstalled Ubuntu Server 22.04, without success. Also I made my netplan without any problem. I put my ssid and password, but even after applying it and/or restarting the machine, it still won't connect.

Comment: From the Amazon Q&A: "Worked out of the box with my new Linux Ubuntu 22.04 build." I recommend that you reinstall 22.04. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please install *wpasupplicant* and, if needed, its dependencies and see if there is any improvement: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/wpasupplicant